# "Edit and Continue" option is missing on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I don't know why, but the ENC option on my VS 2015 Community is missing:

I already made a Full Restore on VS installation, and the issue does not go away. Does someone had this kind of problem?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the Edit and Continue option has been moved in Visual Studio 2015 from where it was previously in 2013, and it's not searchable in Quick Launch or Options Search boxes.

In the options dialog, select debugging on the left. Then on the right, scroll to the very bottom and there will be the options for Edit and Continue.

[image: Edit and Continue Options]

Comment: for me, the flag is already checked, but i'm still unable to edit webforms code-behind...

Comment: I've unchecked the flag, but I'm still able to edit the server side code while debugging. I want to uncheck it because IISExpress stops after debugging and doesn't run without debugging

Comment: use Detach instead of Stop